# Split data frame column by number of characters specified in another column

Tags: r

Sorry if this sounds trivial, but I have been stuck for a while with this.

I want to split a column of strings into two, splitting at the number of the character specified in another column:

```
dat <- tibble(x=c("ABCDEFG", "QRSTUVWXYZ", "FGYHGBJIOW"), y=c(4,3,8)) 
dat
 A tibble: 3 x 2
  x              y
  <chr>      <dbl>
1 ABCDEFG        4
2 QRSTUVWXYZ     3
3 FGYHGBJIOW     8
```

Desired outcome:

```
x1         x2          y
-------------------------  
ABCD       EFG         4
QRS        TUVWXYZ     3
FGYHGBJI   OW          8
```

I have tried using tidy::separate, where it can take the number of characters in the `sep =`, but it won't take the number from another column. I have tried writing a function in the hope that it would do that (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), but it seems it doesn't let the `sep=` part to take column name as arguments (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be:

```
dat <- dat %>% mutate(x1 = substring(x, 1, y),
                      x2 = substring(x, y + 1, nchar(x)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to *@PinotTiger*'s solution using `within`.

```
dat <- within(dat, {
  x2 <- substring(x, y + 1, nchar(x))
  x1 <- substring(x, 1, y)
  rm(x)
})[c(2, 3, 1)]
dat
#         x1      x2 y
# 1     ABCD     EFG 4
# 2      QRS TUVWXYZ 3
# 3 FGYHGBJI      OW 8
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_extract`from the library `stringr`and force the calculation of the number of characters to be extracted each time into the pattern to be matched:

```
dat$x1 <- str_extract(dat$x, paste0("\\w{",dat$y,"}"))
dat$x2 <- str_extract(dat$x, paste0("\\w{",nchar(dat$x) - dat$y,"}$"))

dat
# A tibble: 3 x 4
  x              y x1       x2     
  <chr>      <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  
1 ABCDEFG        4 ABCD     EFG    
2 QRSTUVWXYZ     3 QRS      TUVWXYZ
3 FGYHGBJIOW     8 FGYHGBJI OW
```

Answer (score 0):

An option with `separate` after creating delimiter at the position specified by 'y' with `str_replace`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
dat %>% 
   mutate(x = str_replace(x, sprintf("(.{%d})", y), "\\1,")) %>% 
   separate(x, into = c('x1', 'x2'))
```

Comment: @arkun Slightly deviated but may I ask if my strings in column x contains a mix of alphabets, numbers and other special characters, can I use your method to count only number of _alphabets_ with the `str_replace` function?

Comment: if it is to count you may need str_count